# Unable to install VS10

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

everything is normal until I format my computer and try to install VS10 . Every time I try to install it returns me an error ..

[image]

Log:

http://pastebin.com/pyTRwY7n

Anyone know how can i fix this problem? i already try to install newer version but not sucess

**Windows 7 Ultimate 64bits SP1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved :

Tools used : memtest86+ | http://www.memtest.org/

My computer was a damaged memory comb. After testing and removing the same , everything was back to work normally :)

Answer (score 0):

> [06/30/16,12:36:00] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU:
>   [2] ERROR_INSTALL_PACKAGE_INVALID returned in CRootComponent::Install;
>   the following file is invalid:
>   c:\users\rca\downloads\microsoft.visual.studio.2010.professional\vs_setup.msi

According to your log, your installer is corrupted.

Try to re-download or you can try the help in the below sources:

1. http://geekswithblogs.net/BobHardister/archive/2011/03/29/resolving-visual-studio-2010-sp1-install-problems.aspx
2. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0199518b-a0a9-4d1d-ac4f-1ce3613d3fe2/error-installing-vs2010-on-windows-7-ultimate?forum=vssetup

I hope it help.